# An alignment problem

Tags: align

I do not know how to make the first equality come after `v_{n}(\rho)` aligned with the second equality.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho^{n+1}e^{-\rho/2}\frac{d^{2}v_{n}(\rho)}{d\rho^{2}}
\begin{aligned}[t]
&+\Biggl[(n+1)-\frac{\rho}{2}+(n+1)-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr]\rho^{n}e^{- 
\rho/2}\frac{dv_{n}(\rho)}{d\rho}\\
&+\Biggl[
\begin{aligned}[t]
&-\frac{\rho}{2}+\Biggl[n\Biggl(n+1-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr)-\frac{\rho} 
{2}\Biggl(n+1-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr)\Biggr]\\
&+\Biggl(-\frac{\rho^{2}}{4}+\frac{Ze^{2}}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{\mu} 
{2|E|}}\rho-n(n+1)\Biggr)\Biggr]\rho^{n-1}e^{-\rho/2}v_{n}(\rho)
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\\
&=0\\
\rho v''_{n}(\rho)+(2n+2-\rho)v_{n}(\rho)-(n+1-\lambda)v_{n}(\rho)
&=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\rho^{n+1}\mathrm{e}^{-\rho/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}v_{n}(\rho)}{\mathrm{d}\rho^{2}}
\begin{aligned}[t]
&+\Biggl[(n+1)-\frac{\rho}{2}+(n+1)-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr]\rho^{n}\mathrm{e}^{- 
\rho/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}v_{n}(\rho)}{\mathrm{d}\rho}\\
&+\Biggl[
\begin{aligned}[t]
&-\frac{\rho}{2}+\Biggl[n\Biggl(n+1-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr)-\frac{\rho} 
{2}\Biggl(n+1-\frac{\rho}{2}\Biggr)\Biggr]\\
&+\Biggl(-\frac{\rho^{2}}{4}+\frac{Ze^{2}}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{\mu} 
{2|E|}}\rho-n(n+1)\Biggr)\Biggr]\rho^{n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\rho/2}v_{n}(\rho)
\mathrlap{{}=0}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
&\\
\rho v''_{n}(\rho)+(2n+2-\rho)v_{n}(\rho)-(n+1-\lambda)v_{n}(\rho)
&=0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally like to use `subequations`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    \rho^{n + 1} \mathrm{e}^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho^2}
      & + \Biggl[ (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} + (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr]
        \rho^n \mathrm{e}^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d} v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho} \\
      & + \Biggl[ -\frac{\rho}{2} + \Biggl[ n \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) 
        - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) \Biggr] \\
      & \qquad + \Biggl( -\frac{\rho^2}{4} + \frac{Z e^2}{\hbar} \sqrt{ \frac{\mu}{2 \lvert E\rvert}} \rho
        - n\, (n + 1) \Biggr) \Biggr] \rho^{n - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-\rho / 2} 
        v_n(\rho)
  \end{aligned} &= 0 \\
  \rho\, v''_n\,(\rho) + (2 n + 2 - \rho)\, v_n(\rho) - (n + 1 - \lambda)\, v_n(\rho) &= 0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if possible do not use \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

Comment: @Amir You do not provide a preamble, so I had to guess. If you add the preamble to your question, I can change the answer accordingly. If I just use `\documentclass{article}`, the equation is too wide.

Comment: thanks for your information and sorry. The problem is that when I add this package to my document (book) after pressing the ''pdf'' button the result is half-shown lines of writing.   Thank you.

Comment: @Amir You do not need to add `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` to *your* document. If your document was such that the equation in the question fit, then the equation in the answer will fit as well. You only need to make sure you load `\usepackage{mathtools}`. I am using `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` in this *public* answer so that others who run this code will not get an `overfull hbox` warning.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simpler, natural implementation using `align` and a `b`ottom-`aligned` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    \rho^{n + 1} e^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho^2}
      & + \Biggl[ (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} + (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr]
        \rho^n e^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d} v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho} \\
      & + \Biggl[ -\frac{\rho}{2} + \Biggl[ n \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) 
        - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) \Biggr] \\
      & \qquad + \Biggl( -\frac{\rho^2}{4} + \frac{Z e^2}{\hbar} \sqrt{ \frac{\mu}{2 \lvert E\rvert}} \rho
        - n (n + 1) \Biggr) \Biggr] \rho^{n - 1} e^{-\rho / 2} v_n(\rho)
  \end{aligned} &= 0 \notag \\
  \rho v''_n(\rho) + (2 n + 2 - \rho) v_n(\rho) - (n + 1 - \lambda) v_n(\rho) &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

For a centred equation number, the following works:

[image]

```
\begin{gather}
  \begin{aligned}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      \rho^{n + 1} e^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho^2}
        & + \Biggl[ (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} + (n + 1) - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr]
          \rho^n e^{-\rho / 2} \frac{\mathrm{d} v_n(\rho)}{\mathrm{d} \rho} \\
        & + \Biggl[ -\frac{\rho}{2} + \Biggl[ n \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) 
          - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggl( n + 1 - \frac{\rho}{2} \Biggr) \Biggr] \\
        & \qquad + \Biggl( -\frac{\rho^2}{4} + \frac{Z e^2}{\hbar} \sqrt{ \frac{\mu}{2 \lvert E\rvert}} \rho
          - n (n + 1) \Biggr) \Biggr] \rho^{n - 1} e^{-\rho / 2} v_n(\rho)
    \end{aligned} &= 0 \\
    \rho v''_n(\rho) + (2 n + 2 - \rho) v_n(\rho) - (n + 1 - \lambda) v_n(\rho) &= 0
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

Consider using indentation and/or spacing in your code in order to see aligned elements more clearly.

Comment: I also had this first but I think the OP wants the equation number in the vertical center. In your example it looks like only the second equality is numbered. (I am also wondering why your code has so many ingredients that were specific to my answer such as the upright differential `d`s. I personally also like to discriminate between the electric charge and Euler's number, which is why the latter are upright in my answer.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I've added an option related to that, thanks. I always use `\mathrm{d}` for differentials, starting with the OP's code...

Comment: I would appreciate it a lot if you could consider not to self-advertise your proposal as "simpler".

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: The reference to "simpler" points to the OP's implementation using a mixture of `equation`, `split` and two `t`-op-`aligned` constructions. You've used something similar, but that's reference is coincidental. Additionally, indentation and spacing adds clarity to the code.